# Assign random value to form

Tags: forms, scala, random, playframework, playframework-2.2

I am using this code to assign a default random value to a form field ("token"):

```
  val userForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "token" -> default(text, (randomString("0123456789abcdef")(40))),
      "username" -> optional(text),
      "email" -> email,
      "password" -> nonEmptyText,
      "gender" -> nonEmptyText
    )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
  )
```

It seems like the "token" random value is generated only once and never changes after that. Any way of solving this issue?

Comment: I'm not that experienced with `play`, but is it possible to change this `val` to a `def`? Like: `def userForm = Form(...)`

Comment: Thanks Kigyo, it does work with "def", but won't it miss the point of performance? I do not want to create a new instance of userForm on each user request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own `Mapping` that takes a thunk. The following is *inspired* by the `Forms` [source](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/Forms.scala):

```
def defaultThunk[A](mapping: Mapping[A], value: =>A): Mapping[A] = 
      OptionalMapping(mapping).transform(_.getOrElse(value), Some(_))
```

As `value` is used in a anonymous function it should be getting called every time, giving a different random number.

So instead of using

```
"token" -> default(text, (randomString("0123456789abcdef")(40))),
```

use instead:

```
"token" -> defaultThunk(text, (randomString("0123456789abcdef")(40))),
```

Comment: Thanks ggovan, sorry, I do not know Scala that well to use your example. Can you please explain how it connects?

Comment: You just have to put the `def defaultThunk` before you create your form, and then use it instead of `default`.

Comment: Thanks ggovan, I don't fully understand it, but it works just great!

Answer (score 0):

It is like this because your form is immutable.

As @Kigyo suggest in comment, I also think that you can try change it to function, but it will be not efficient when you want bind form data from request after that.

Another solution is to use *fill* method on form, something like that:

```
userForm.fill(User((randomString("0123456789abcdef")(40)), None, "", "")
```

It will return new form with filled data. That form you can put to your view template.

However, I am not sure if it is the best solution...

Comment: Thanks. I doesn't help me, since the whole point is to assign the values to User using: userForm.bindFromRequest.fold

Comment: I understand your point. But eventually, if you filled it properly in view, you will have it filled properly also after binding. However @ggovan idea is mutch better :). Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could write in your template as

```
 @inputText(userForm("token").copy(value=Some(randomString("0123456789abcdef")(40))))
```

or pass the randomString as parameter to template and use as

```
@(userForm: Form[_], randStr)

 @inputText(userForm("token").copy(value=Some(randStr)))
```